# lowpass filter question

Tags: audio, analog

I tried two solutions for a lowpass filter:

[image: lowpass]

Fig.1 - Normal RC lowpass with cutoff range of about 30-300hz according to the frequency cutoff formula.
Fig.2 - Acoustically, this is closer to what I was looking for but I don't know what happens exactly.

Two questions:

1. The filter in fig.1 doesn't give the cutoff range I was looking for because of the mixing resistor. Is it possible to isolate the mixing resistors from the RC filter using minimal space (no IC or only one IC with just a few components)?
2. As for the solution in fig.2: with R1 = 0 it works normally as an RC filter; in the initial range of the potentiometer (about 0-500R), more than affecting the cutoff, it sounds like a gain control for the high frequencies; in the rest of the range it seems like a gain control for the whole audio signal, without affecting the cutoff. Is it correct to consider the potentiometer R1 in fig.2 like a gain for the high frequencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case ends up as a lowpass filter, the second case is either a lowpass (R=0), or a shelf lowpass (R>0). Both attenuate the DC to some extent, due to the input pots:

[image: test]

For the 1st case, you can't isolate with only RC elements, you'll need some active element (opamp would be a good choice) for that. For the 2nd case, I have no idea what this means to you

> Acoustically, this is closer to what I was looking for

but the corner frequency is lower than the 1st case, and due to the "shelf" response, high frequencies are preserved, but attenuated. I guess that might sound to you as more "rich", more clear. I also don't know what *range* means to you here

> The filter in fig.1 doesn't give the range I was looking for

but it seems to me that the corner frequency in the 1st case is ~50 Hz, while for the 2nd one it's ~6 Hz. You should first establish some parameters before continuing, for example what range of frequencies do you want, or is it a simple or shelf lowpass that you need. When I say frequency range I don't mean "somewhere between 30-300 Hz". Establish your goals first, then build.

Comment: If in doubt, a SPICE simulator can provide great insight.

Comment: Thanks for the accurate response. I edited the question to clarify that I was referring to the cutoff range. I added a unity gain op-amp after the mixing stage and I think I can control the cutoff range easily now. In fig.1, how can the cutoff be ~50hz if I have a pot that changes the cutoff? Assuming that the input gain is maximum (so the input pot gives 0 resistance) shouldn't the cutoff vary between ~29hz (R=110k) and ~318hz (R=10k)? As for fig.2, the shelf response explains what I'm hearing. In the plot, I don't understand why there are 5 steps for x and 10 blue graphs, though.

Comment: @Loo In my example I made your `R10` in fig. 1 a fixed `50k`, for simplicity. That's why there is only a black trace showing a fixed 50 Hz cutoff. The blue traces are for various values of your `R1` in fig. 2: 1, 10, 100, 250, 1k. Continuous lines for magnitude, dotted lines for phase. Maybe I should have done it similarly for fig. 1, but for minimum and maximum values of the pot, the cutoff will vary from ~29~215 Hz (the gain pot will influence). It will still be a lowpass, only, as opposed to a shelf lowpass.